# Restart application with Kill process id

Tags: c#

I want to restart my application with some condition. But I want to kill the process first. So when I start it again then a new process id should be assigned. How to do this?

I googled it but I can't the find perfect answer.

I had written following code:

```
Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath);
Threat.Thread.Sleep(2000);
Environment.Exit(-1);
```

Comment: can you show what you have tried ?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Starting a new process will give you a new process ID.

Comment: But I want to kill previous Process id @Blorgbeard